# What are the constant values for R.anim.slide_out_left & R.anim.slide_in_right

Tags: android, android-animation, xamarin

What are the constant values for

```
R.anim.slide_out_left
```

and

```
R.anim.slide_in_right
```

I need them as Xamarin Android does not seem to have a binding for them in the

```
Android.Resource.Animation
```

enum.

Also, would there be any issues passing those constant values directly into Activity::overridePendingTransition given my app tagets API level 10+?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use the constant that is supplied by the system you should probably make a copy of the entire animation xml file and point to your own copy, rather than hardcoding the constant int value. AFAIK you have no guarantee that the int constant will not change at some point, which if it happened would almost certainly break your app.

Those map to these two animation xml files:

**slide_in_right.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

**slide_in_left.xml**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

You can find them inside your copy of the SDK look for this path:

```
[sdk]\platforms-[version]\data\res\anim\
```

They should be inside that folder.